# Swagger / Swashbucle - Hide Preview of Available Values of Dropdown

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swagger-codegen

I'm currently working with a webapi scenario where we're exposing a growing list of enum values for input. In the swagger these are displayed as a dropdown, which is perfect for selection.

However, in swagger the values of the dropdown are "previewed" before pressing the "Try it out"-button as "Available values:". I would like to remove this preview, as the list has grown to the point where it's jarring, but I haven't found any setting to do so.

Does anyone know how, or if, this is possible? We're using the standard Swashbuckle/OpenAPI nugets for .NET5/6/7

[image: Available values example]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best option, but at least it can be a workaround. My idea is setting custom css for swagger UI. We can see the `previewed` values has class `parameter__enum`, so in my .net 6 web api project, I created `wwwroot/swagger/Custom.css` and used it in the API with

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(opts => {
    opts.InjectStylesheet("/swagger/Custom.css");
});

...

app.UseStaticFiles();
```

[image]

Comment: This is currently our fallback solution, but with some inline css to avoid having to add another resource to the repo. I'm hoping someone will have a "better" solution, but my hope is dimming. +1

Comment: yes, let's see if anyone else can find a option in swagger to change the appearence.